# CRITICAL_SECTION doesn't have DebugInfo

Tags: c, winapi, critical-section

I'm trying to get a look at the DebugInfo of my CRITICAL_SECTION during execution of my win32 program, and after using InitializeCriticalSection then the DebugInfo pointer is -1.

```
CRITICAL_SECTION myCS;
InitializeCriticalSection(&myCS);
printf("%d", myCS.DebugInfo); // prints:  -1
```

I also tried `InitializeCriticalSectionEx(&myCS, 4000, 0);` and had the same results.  Also get the same thing regardless if I have entered this Critical Section or not.  Is it possible to access this DebugInfo, and how should it be done?

Comment: I assume you've built with debugging turned on for the compiler?

Comment: Entirely possible that the version of Windows you're using doesn't use that field. Internal structures can / do change without warning.

Comment: @BillyONeal I can see other CRITICAL_SECTION objects in the process that do have this DebugInfo (via WinDbg, !locks).

Comment: What are you going to do with this information?

Comment: FWIW, you print a pointer using `%p`. Anyway, how can we reproduce what you observe. You'll need to let us know what system you use. Because this private field is system specific.

Comment: @segfault: They could easily only fill that field in when running under a debugger (e.g. by checking [`IsDebuggerPresent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx)) or similar. Also, they could choose to power `!locks` with completely different machinery than the "DebugInfo" field. After all, SRWLOCKs are what you'd want to use in new code and they have no place where a pointer could be stashed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, but is unanswered.

You can force the creation of the `DebugInfo` structure by calling `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` with `RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_FLAG_FORCE_DEBUG_INFO` flag:

```
InitializeCriticalSectionEx(&cs, 4000, RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_FLAG_FORCE_DEBUG_INFO);
```

This flag is not included on the [Microsoft InitializeCriticalSectionEx documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionex), but it is defined on `winnt.h`

Comment: Thanks gusitoguay! For the life of me I can't remember why I wanted this, but at least now we know.